# install.packages(repos=NULL) in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

Suddenly RStudio is ignoring the `repos = NULL` paramater and trying to install from the repositories.

I am calling: `install.packages("d:/R/install/truncdist_1.0-1.zip", repos=NULL)`

But it is ignoring the `repos=NULL` and trying to connect to two repositories:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to connect to 'www.vps.fmvz.usp.br' on port 80.    

Warning in install.packages :
    unable to access index for repository http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.0

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to connect to 'www.stats.ox.ac.uk' on port 80.

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
```

In the end it installs the package correctly from the local directory, but it takes forever to do it.

This problem does not happen when using only R, it is happening just in RStudio (and RStudio is my main GUI at work).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

PS: I am using RStudio 0.97.551 and R version 3.0.1 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bypass the extra things that RStudio does when installing packages by calling `utils::install.packages` directly. Alternatively, under the Tools menu, there is an "Install Packages..." dialog which allows in the first dropdown to select installing from "Package Archive File (.zip; .tar.gz)"

The fact that the RStudio version of `install.packages` does not respect `repos=NULL` should probably be filed as a bug with RStudio.

Comment: The `utils::install.packages(name, repos=NULL)` worked perfectly, thanks, did not know that RStudio had masked the original install.packages (but I should have thought of that!). As to the dropdown menu, it gives the same bug because it generates the very same call as typing directly.

Comment: Since the dialog box fails in the same way, it is definitely a bug and should be reported.

Comment: I have sent them an email.